GraphicsRow cutting off tick labels
The code
Table[Plot[x^i, {x, 0, 1}], {i, {2, 4, 8}}]

produces

which looks fine. If I now try
GraphicsRow[%]

I get the following:

Notice that the tick labels are cut off both left and bottom.
Is there some setting on GraphicsRow that will work around this problem? I've tried ImageSize->All, which only makes it look worse.

My best advice would be to avoid GraphicsRow unless it's really necessary. Just use Row, or even better, a Grid.

Unless I'm mistaken, Row requires that each Plot command provide an image size, I think, in order to get decent results. Is that right?

If you use Grid, then no :) For example: Grid[{Table[Plot[x^i, {x, 0, 1}], {i, {2, 4, 8}}]}]

Can someone explain why this question was closed? If this was a "trivial error", can someone say what that was? if it is answered in the docs, where? Sorry, I just don't understand.

I recommend to give ImagePadding a try
pt = Table[Plot[x^i, {x, 0, 1}, ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}], {i, {2, 4, 8}}];
GraphicsRow[pt]



This works great. I would have preferred being able to deal with it in the GraphicsRow statement, but this is fine.
